# Change Column Ordering in Mobile View with React-Bootstrap

Tags: reactjs, react-bootstrap

I'm using React-Bootstrap with my React project and wanted to change the column ordering when in mobile or XS view.

The code below gives me a nice 2 column layout and responds to 1 column when viewport is xs:

```
    return (
      <Container>
        <Row className={styles.section}>
          <Col xs={12} md={6}>
            <h2>{this.props.heading}</h2>
            <p>{this.props.content}</p>
          </Col>
          <Col>
            <p>
              <img src={this.props.img} />
            </p>
          </Col>
        </Row>
      </Container>
    );
```

I want to make the second column (the one with `{this.props.img}` ) to be on top in xs/mobile view.

So I added `xs={{ order: 1 }}` to that Column:

```
<Col xs={{ order: 1 }}>
   <p>
     <img src={this.props.img} />
   </p>
</Col>
```

However that did not work. With vanilla Bootstrap, you can add `class="order-xs-1"` and that would work.

Any tips on this would be great, thanks!

Answer (score 18, accepted):

I think you should define both `span` and `order` on each `Col`.
Something like this:

```
<Container>
  <Row>
    <Col xs={{ span: 12, order: 2 }} md={{ span: 6, order: 1 }}> First col </Col>
    <Col xs={{ span: 12, order: 1 }} md={{ span: 6, order: 2 }}> Second col </Col>
  </Row>
</Container>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can also code like as the vanilla (or original structure)

```
                        <div className="row ">
                            <div className="col-md-5 order-md-2">LOGO</div>
                            <div className="col-md-7 order-md-1">TITLE</div>
                        </div>
```

What will happen here,
this will show like this

[image]

Then on MOBILE VIEW

[image]

(listen, it didnt work if i put the title first on the code, but if you put the logo first it will work just like the example above. I tested my self on my project)

Answer (score 0):

actually above solution works but it results in 2 different rows for each col, so when you have more than 2 rows, the result will be more visible. meaning that if you have 3 cols like:

```
<Row>
   <Col xs={{span: 12, order: 2 }}> 1st col but in small screen, 2nd col </Col>
   <Col xs={{span: 12, order: 1 }}> 2nd col but in small screen, 1st col </Col>
   <Col xs={{span: 12, order: 3 }}> 3rd col </Col>
</Row>
```

the result will be like below in wide screens:

[                                    1st col but in small screen, 2nd col       ]
[1st col but in small screen, 2nd col                                           ]
[                                                                        3rd col]

so it's not looking so good. 
I found another solution to this. I had 3 cols as I mentioned, I just wanted the first and the second to be displaced with each other. the first was my cart icon and the second was my logo. so I defined 2 states with initial values:

```
this.state = {
   logo_col_order: 2,
   cart_col_order: 1
}
```

then in componentDidMount I checked window innerWidth to see if it's mobile, change the order of cols:

```
componentDidMount() {

if(window.innerWidth <= 760) {
  this.setState({
    logo_col_order: 1,
    cart_col_order: 2,
  })
}
```

}

then I changed my components order to the states value:

```
<Row>
   <Col xs={{order: cart_col_order }}> 1st col but in small screen, 2nd col </Col>
   <Col xs={{order: logo_col_order }}> 2nd col but in small screen, 1st col </Col>
   <Col xs={{order: 3 }}> 3rd col </Col>
</Row>
```

Be sure that all your columns have the property `xs={{order: someNumber}}`, otherwise your layout will look messy and the columns that don't have order property, will be loosing their location in the screen.
I hope this help.